# Web view using ICS Android OS

Tags: android, android-webview, android-websettings

wvtxtcastdet.loadData(text, "text/html", "utf-8")

where text is the HTML content. It works fine in every OS. But in ICS getting this error

java.lang.Throwable: EventHub.removeMessages(int what = 107) is not supported before the WebViewCore is set up.

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: String text = "<html><body>"

                       + "<p align=\"justify\">"                

                        + "<font color='white' style='line-height:1.2em; font-style:italic;font-weight:bold;font-size:11px; font-family:Times New Roman' >"+textcastdet+"</font>"

                       + "</p> "

                       + "</body></html>";

              
   try {
   
   wvtxtcastdet.loadData(text, "text/html", "utf-8");
    
   }
   
   catch (Exception ex) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    ex.printStackTrace();
   }

Comment: java.lang.Throwable: EventHub.removeMessages(int what = 107) is not supported before the WebViewCore is set up.
at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub.removeMessages (WebViewCore.java:1671)
at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub.access$7800                at android.webkit.WebViewCore.removeMessages(WebViewCore.java:1783)
at android.webkit.WebView.sendOurVisibleRect(WebView.java:2858)
at android.webkit.ZoomManager.setZoomScale(ZoomManager.java:586)
at android.webkit.ZoomManager.access$1700(ZoomManager.java:49)
at android.webkit.ZoomManager$PostScale.run(ZoomManager.java:977)

Comment: are you trying to zoom ?

Comment: can you close this question as you duplicated it with apparentyl more info ?